# Converting local GmailApp.sendEmail (GAS) to Web App script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

I have a working Google apps script set up to send an automated email (GmailApp.sendEmail) when I click a button in the workbook.

However, I am trying to convert the script to Google Web App so that any users within my organization will have authorization to run the script and trigger the automated email by pressing the button.

I'm a little lost on how to adapt the local code from getui(). I know that I need to add a function such as doget(e) and deploy as a web app, but I'm not well-versed enough in Web App to edit the code.

Here is my working local code:

```
// This constant is written in column E for rows for which an email
// has been sent successfully.
var EMAIL_SENT = 'E-MAIL SENT';
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

/**
 * Sends non-duplicate emails with data from the current spreadsheet.
 */
function email(){
  var rng = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A2:F2')
  var checkvalue = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('E2').getValue();
  var email = rng.getValues()[0];
  var data = rng.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
  var row = data[i];
  var emailSent = checkvalue; // emailSent confirmation cell
  if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT) { // Prevents sending duplicates
  GmailApp.sendEmail(email[0], email[1], email[2]);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('E2').setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
      // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  }
 }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Code.gs:

```
function email(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById("SpreadsheetId");//need spreadsheet id
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName("SheetName");//when you open up a spreadsheet like this the active sheet is alway ss.getSheets()[0] the left most sheet so you should user get sheet by name instead.
  var rg=sh.getRange('A2:F2');
  var email=rg.getValues()[0];
  if (email[4]!="EMAIL_SENT") { 
  GmailApp.sendEmail(email[0], email[1], email[2]);
  sh.getRange('E2').setValue("EMAIL_SENT");
  }
}

function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('html filename without extension');
}
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <base target="_top">
  </head>
<body>
  <input type="button" value="Send" onClick="google.script.run.email();" />
</body>
</html>
```

[Client to Server Communication](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication)

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks, Cooper. Really appreciate you cleaning up the code and including html!

Comment: I just noticed one little glitch in my thinking. How would I edit the openById("SpreadsheetId") line to have the script actively pull the ID versus being hardcoded? My problem is that users will be saving off copies off this master template and making job specifics edits, then emailing out using the script above. However, currently the saved off copies cause the email to be sent from the original master template...I believe because of the "SpreadsheetId" being static.

Comment: I often store stuff like that in a sheet name Globals where a store a table of key value pairs.  Then I can't retrieve it with `getGlobals('SpreadsheetID') `